# find the value within a range using percent

Tags: javascript, math

I have a range of number
`40 to 255` where 40 is 0% and 255 is 100%
how can I get the number which is 50% ?

I tried searching for a way to do this but can't find any.

Comment: (255 - 40)/2 + 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have (255-40) = 100%
- 1% = (255-40)/100
- 50% = ((255-40)/100) * 50 = 107.5
- Since you have offset of 40 at the beginning, 50% from offset = 107.5 + 40 = 147.5

Comment: if I want to get the percentage using a value how do I use the solution above?

Comment: % value = ((your value - 40 offset) / (255 - 40 offset)) * 100. For 147.5, you'll get 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Kiran s answer with some generic Javascript

```js
const rangeMin = 40;
const rangeMax = 255;
const percentage = 50;

const valueFromPercentage = (((rangeMax - rangeMin) / 100) * percentage ) + rangeMin;
```

```js
const rangeMin = 40;
const rangeMax = 255;
const value = 147;

const percentageFromValue = ((value - rangeMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin)) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any number `c` in an interval `[a, b]` can be written as a linear combination of the two endpoints 
`c = a*x + b*(1-x)` for some `x ∈ [0, 1]`.

For `[a, b] = [0, 100]`, the number `c = 50` can be written as `0*0.5 + 100*0.5` so `x = 0.5`.

If the interval `[0, 100]` is linearly mapped to `[40, 255]`, the ratio `x = 0.5` will stay the same, and so `c` gets mapped to `c' = 40*0.5 + 255*0.5 = (40 + 255)/2 = 147.5`.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following

```
(255 - 40)/2 + 40
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).